# in_array not finding the value which is present?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Here is the code to check if the contact_id is present in the pool of particular user's pool

```
function checkid()
{
    $conn = connectPDO();

    $query = "SELECT contact_id FROM contacts WHERE contact_by = :cby";
    $st = $conn->prepare( $query );
    $st->bindValue( ':cby', $this->contact_by, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetchALL();
    $conn = null;

    print_r($this->contact_id); //1
    print_r($row);     //Array ( [0] => Array ( [contact_id] => 1 [0] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [contact_id] => 3 [0] => 3 ) ) 

    if( !in_array( $this->contact_id, $row ))
    {
        echo 'You are not authorised to update the details of this contact';
    }
}
```

Here is the url:

```
http://localhost/contmanager/home.php?action=update&contactid=1
```

One thing i noticed is that, when i use fetch instead of fetchall, it works fine for contact_id '1' but fails when using fetchALL.

Comment: Sorry, but this question can easily be answered with "RTFM". Therefore, as it is now, it doesn't show any research effort. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array` not works for multidimentional array's, A workaroud will be:

```
foreach( $row as $each ){  #collect all the ids in an array
    $temp[] = $each['contact_id'];
}
```

Then check for `in_array`:

```
if( !in_array( $this->contact_id, $temp )){
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks for quick reply. Sad, i got 3 down votes but i learnt a new thing.

Answer (score -1):

use this function for multidimentional array's :

```
function in_multiarray($elem, $array)
{
    $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
    $bottom = 0;
    while($bottom <= $top)
    {
        if($array[$bottom] == $elem)
            return true;
        else 
            if(is_array($array[$bottom]))
                if(in_multiarray($elem, ($array[$bottom])))
                    return true;

        $bottom++;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

example :

```
$array = array( array( 'contact_id' => '1' , 1 ) , array( 'contact_id' => '3' , 3 ) );
var_dump( in_multiarray( 1 , $array  ) );
```

Comment: why give -1 ? what is the problem ?